# preg_match for certain part of the comments

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-replace-callback

i want to find certain part of the comments. following are some examples

```
/*
 * @todo name another-name taskID
 */

/* @todo name another-name taskID */
```

currently im using following regular expression

```
'/\*[[:space:]]*(?=@todo(.*))/i'
```

this returns following:

```
* @todo name another-name taskID
or
* @todo name another-name taskID */
```

how can i just get just @todo and names, but not any asterisks?

desired output

```
@todo name another-name taskID
@todo name another-name taskID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$str=<<<STR
/*
 * @todo name another-name taskID 1
 */

/* @todo name another-name taskID 2 */
STR;
$match=null;
preg_match_all("/\*[[:space:]]*(@todo[^(\*\/$)]*)/i",$str,$match,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($match);
```

echos

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => * @todo name another-name taskID 1

            [1] => @todo name another-name taskID 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => * @todo name another-name taskID 2 
            [1] => @todo name another-name taskID 2 
        )

)
```

Not a perfect solution (notice the line-ending in `$match[0][0]`) though.

Comment: is there a way, i can ignore the first astrick sign? without removing the check

Comment: @Basit That's why I use capturing. You can see `$match[*][1]` are all `@todo .....`.